# How to make bash think `-mthreads` word as `-pthread`?

Tags: bash

So I want to make my bash to replace word `` `-mthreads `` each time I input it with word `-pthread`. Is such thing possible  and how to do it?

Comment: Why????????????

Comment: At the prompt or in scripts. To you want the `p` to turn into `m` on the command line as soon as you type the `d`, or the word replaced upon pressing enter? To you want it unconditionally (-pthreads-safe to be turned into -mthreads-safe?)? Any way to bypass that substitution? Is switching to another shell (like zsh) an option? All of those should be possible with zsh, some of them might be possible with bash.

Answer (score 2):

In `zsh` you can do this with a global alias:

```
alias -g -- -mthreads=-pthread
```

But if you need to stick with bash, make a shell function to filter the arguments, as @Kyle Jones explained.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any way to make it apply to all command lines, but you can do the substitution per command by writing a shell function for each command for which you'd like the substitution to happen.  Example: for `gcc` you'd write:

```
function gcc {
   local args=""
   local arg
   for arg in $@
   do
      case $arg in
         -mthreads) arg=-pthreads
      esac
      args="$args $arg"
   done
   command gcc $args
}
```